# Use data from firebase out of the .on() function

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I am quite new with Typescript and do not know how can I use the variables latitue1 and latitude2 outside of the this.ref.on('value', (snapshot) function  and add the values to the locations array.
Could you please help me?
Thanks!

```
this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

  this.ref.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    //console.log(firebaseToArray(snapshot)[0].latitude);
  var latitude1 = firebaseToArray(snapshot)[0].latitude;
  var latitude2 = firebaseToArray(snapshot)[1].latitude;

});


  var locations = [
    ['3/4', latitude1, 2.1743558],
    ['1/6', latitude2, 2.1843558]
  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply like this maybe

```
this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

let locations

this.ref.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    //console.log(firebaseToArray(snapshot)[0].latitude);
    let latitude1 = firebaseToArray(snapshot)[0].latitude;
    let latitude2 = firebaseToArray(snapshot)[1].latitude;

    locations = [
        ['3/4', latitude1, 2.1743558],
        ['1/6', latitude2, 2.1843558]
    ];
});

// use locations there
```

But it really depends on the bigger picture. I mean, `locations` would be available after the async event (`this.ref.on`). So you have to figure out how the remaining part of your code should look.

Comment: Yes, this is the typical way. But I wanted to know if there is no other way to pass the information outside of the function?
I am thinking in a more complicated scenario where I maybe need to use the variables of one function into another. thanks!

Comment: Callback are quite tricky. That's why there's such a thing as "callback hell". So probably use async/await instead of callbacks. But before that, you should promisify your callbacks. Google "js promisify callback" and "async/await"

Comment: Thank you for the info!! I'll have a look

Comment: @SergioHV You are welcome! Consider upvote/select as the best answer if I've helped, as well.